# Is there any TestNG Listener method to execute after each Classes in Package

Tags: testng

I have set of Classes which contains multiple @Test under multiple packages. I want to know method(preferably TestNG Listener method) which will execute after each Class execution completes. Something similar like @AfterClass annotation method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the Answer:
We have couple of methods onBeforeClass and onAfterClass in [IClassListener](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/IClassListener.html) interface.